# Validation of Text field while Click on submit button

Tags: perl, cgi

I am using Perl CGI. I have created some text fields and getting those values.
But i want if user leave the text field blank when he click on submit button then instead of run a script it should give  a popup. Please any body suggest me something..???

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want server side validation on that? I think you need to use JavaScript for client-end validation.

make me correct if I am wrong?

with JavaScript;

```
function Validator(theForm){
  var error = "";
  if (theForm.dd.options[0].selected == true){
    error += "Please select from the drop-down list.\n";
  }

  if (theForm.words.value == ""){
    error += "Please fill in the text element.\n";
  }

 //etc etc...
}
```

You just need to use onClick event of the html button and call this method with Form element in the document.

Comment: IMHO A combination of client side (comfortable, minimizing net traffic) and server side (security) validation would be the best strategy.

Comment: How can i embed javascript in perl??

Comment: @user970553: Do not embed it in Perl, embed it into the generated HTML.